# Create MS SQL Procedure with multiple pass parameters and one output won't work

Tags: sql-server

I've made some code in sql server to get random float numbers. It pass rage and out a number, but it shows syntax error. Can someone show me, where it is and how I shoul correct it?
That's my code

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE getAmount( @MinVal float, 
        @MaxVal float)
        @out float OUTPUT
        AS
        SELECT @out = ((@MaxVal - @MinVal)
        * RAND() + @MinVal)
        RETURN
```

Comment: Answer is already given. One suggestion use "SET NOCOUNT ON" and keep all the keywords in uppercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OUT paramater needs to be inside the parenthesis;

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getAmount( @MinVal float, 
        @MaxVal float,
        @out float OUTPUT )
        AS
        SELECT @out = ((@MaxVal - @MinVal)
        * RAND() + @MinVal)
        RETURN
```